# Audio Stream wont play while running, only during debug. JAVA

Tags: java, audio, synchronization

***UPDATED:***

**The audio is not completely playing because the main() that calls it is ending!  How can I make sure that the file is played before the main() that it is called from closes?**

I am new to programming and know the basics. I am just learning JAVA for a hobby.  No formal education in Java.

When I run the java class that calls this routine below, there is no audio played.  When I am in debug mode an place a break somewhere in the routine, I resume the debugger and the wave file stored in the byte array will play.

I have no threads that are programmed into the other class that calls this.  The byte array wave file is constructed by another class and sent into this routine.

I assume the problem is caused by the class that creates the wave file not being able to complete it in time for the call to playByteWaveAudio.

**Does this routine need to wait for the byte array to be completed? What can I do to make sure that the byte array will play?**

This is the code in java that is giving me a problem:

```
public class PlayByteWaveAudio {

public PlayByteWaveAudio() {
    System.err.println("Need Byte Array with wave file data! ");
}

public PlayByteWaveAudio(byte[] playWave) {

        InputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayInputStream(playWave);

        try {
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(byteArray);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

            clip.open(ais);
              //if I have a breakpoint in this area, during DEBUG, i can continue
              //and the wave byte array will play just fine.
              //During regular run(without debug), there is no sound.
            clip.start();
            clip.flush();
        } catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create a constructor which isn't supposed to be called? When you just omit the constructor `public PlayByteWaveAudio()` while having one with arguments, you will get a compile-time error when trying to create a `new PlayByteWaveAudio()` instead of a runtime error.

Comment: I created it because I do not know programming well enough!  :)  iI will no longer do that. Thank you for pointing that out.